# chrome.runtime.sendMessage - Recieving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So i'm trying to send a message from my content script `BlockElement.js` to my background script `background.js` but Im always recieving this error in my chrome console and therefore it's not working.
[image]

Any ideas or help would be appreciated. I currently have messages sending between my popup.js and another content script fine, the trouble just seems to be from a content script. **is it because a content script can't call out?**

Note that both BlockElement.js and background.js are using only the code taken from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging as i've tried with my own and that didn't work either

**Manifest**

```
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "desc",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "Interface/popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "run_at": "document_end",
          "js": ["jquery.js","BlockElement.js","SelectElement.js"]
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
```

**BlockElement.js**

contains only this, this code throws an error in the browser no matter which content script i put it in.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

Comment: Looks like a typo in manifest.json: Background.js vs background.js.

Comment: @wOxxOm actually just a typo on here, they match - ill edit now. However this error occurs even without the background file or it's code, if I try and send a message out from any content script i get the error from the picture.

Comment: The error message is really unambiguous: it's saying that you don't have a listener which may happen only if there is no background script running at all. Assuming that the real code matches the question... Make sure you did reload the extension after editing the background script or manifest.json on `chrome://extensions` page.

Comment: I’ll give it another attempt tomorrow - but the listener had definitely been put In place. I did see a post somewhere about the content script being loaded before the background script. Could it be anything to do with that?

Comment: That problem is specific to persistent background scripts. The nonpersistent ones like yours will be started by messaging automatically even during Chrome's startup. At least they should be.

Comment: I see thanks, Overall I’m just trying to send the URL from the background script to the content script. Now if this continues to not work is it reasonable to just get it from the window in Js on the content script?

Comment: Yes, `location.href` in content script should be 100% reliable.